# Add multiple imageview in uitableviewcell iphone

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have 2 image view on a single table view cell. and i am downloading the images using "Lazy Table sample". but now but when 1 image downloading completed then i am showing 1 image on cell. but when other 2nd image downloading complted  then how i update the cell using "cellForRowAtIndexPath". can any one suggest me.

thank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:
```

Look [UITableView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class reference